# How to invoke events on a pod using kubectl

Tags: python, events, kubernetes, monitoring

I would like to monitor the pods running on my cluster, using a python script. I wrote that script, which will check if there are new events happening on my pods (+extra logic and custom logging).

Now I would like to know if my script is correct. **Is there a way to invoke events on the pods by hand, i.e. using kubectl?**

Thanks!

Comment: If you give a downvote, pls also give an answer

Comment: The downvotes are coming from the formatting of your question. Are you asking us if your script is correct? You didn't provide it.

Comment: In other words please provide your script.

Comment: Sorry, for the formatin. I am asking how to invoke events on the pods using kubectl.

Answer (score 0):

To get events you can use `kubectl get events`, keep in mind that events are namespaced. This means you need to specify a namespace object, like this `kubectl get events --namespace=my-namespace`. Or you can list all namespaces by using `kubectl get events --all-namespaces`.

You can read the detailed explanation and other examples of debugging Kubernetes inside [Application Introspection and Debugging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/)